# NestJS Gateway dependency injection

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs, provider, gateway

I have a service called "PlayerService" and the gateway calls "Player Gateway", the PlayersGateway has dependency of PlayerService, but I can't inject o service inside gateway.

**PlayerGateway**

```
@UseInterceptors(RedisPropagatorInterceptor)
@WebSocketGateway()
@Injectable()
export class PlayerGateway
  extends BaseGateway
  implements OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayInit, OnGatewayDisconnect {

constructor(private playerService: PlayerService) {
    super();
  }
```

**PlayerService**

```
@Injectable()
export class PlayerService extends BaseService<Player> {
  protected fieldsSearchable: FieldsSearchable = {};

  private logger = new Logger('PlayerService');

  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(PlayerRepository)
    repository: PlayerRepository,
    @Inject(REQUEST) protected request: Request,
    private redisService: RedisService,
  ) {
    super();
    this.setRepository(repository);
  }
```

**PlayerModule**

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Player, PlayerRepository]),
    RedisModule,
    SocketModule,
    RedisPropagatorModule,
  ],
  controllers: [PlayerController],
  exports: [TypeOrmModule, PlayerService],
  providers: [PlayerService, PlayerGateway],
})
export class PlayerModule {}
```

**Modules.ts**

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    RedisModule,
    SocketModule,
    RedisPropagatorModule,
    SessionModule,
    PlayerModule,
  ],
  exports: [RedisModule, SocketModule],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [ServerGateway, NetworkGateway],
})
```

What I want to know is how can I inject the service inside gateway or a way to make something like this rsrs

Comment: Use the request object on the controller, avoid use it on the service pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PlayerService is trying to inject the request:

`@Inject(REQUEST) protected request: Request`

This doesn't make sense for constructing an instance of a Gateway as it should be independent of any individual HTTP request. Do you actually need to have access to the request inside your `PlayerService`? If so you'll have to split this apart into separate services